# Printing only one error message out of multiply if statements

Tags: java

I have a method that checks to see if the month, day, year of an inputted date is correct, the method work right except that if the inputted dates month/year/day are invalid, then it prints the error messages for each check (month/day/year) that is false. I only one error message instead of all three.

here is the code of the method that I have:

```
  //Check to see if the date is valid
  public static boolean isValid(int day, int month, int year){

     boolean monthValid, yearValid, dayValid;
     boolean check = true;
     int dayNumber = 0;

        //check to see if the month is valid
        if(month <= 12 && month > 0){

           monthValid = true;

        }else{

           monthValid = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid month.");
           check = false;

        }

        //Check to see if the year is valid
        if (year <= 3000 && year >= 1){

           yearValid = true;

        }else{

           yearValid = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid Year.");
           check = false;

        }

        //assigns month to a number
        if (month == JAN || month == MAR || month == MAY || month == JUL || month == AUG ||month == OCT || month == DEC){

           dayNumber = LONG;

        }else if (month == APR || month == JUN || month == SEP || month == NOV){

           dayNumber = SHORT;

        }else if (month == FEB && true == isLeapYear(year)){

           dayNumber = AKWARD;


        }else if( month == FEB){

           dayNumber = MINI;

        }

        //check to see if day is valid
        if (day < dayNumber && day > 0 || day == dayNumber){

           dayValid = true;

        }else if(day == AKWARD && false == isLeapYear(year)){

           System.out.println("Invalid day number for February for given year.");   
           check = false;

        }else if( day > dayNumber || day < 0){

           dayValid = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid day number for month.");
           check = false;
        }
  return check; 
  }
```

So if the inputted date is 13/34/3001(MM/DD/YYYY)
the output is:

Enter a date in the three number format, m/d/year: 13/34/3001

Invalid month.

Invalid Year.

Invalid day number for month.

Again, I only need to print one error message out of those three.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting check = false, you could just immediately return false when an error message is written:

```
yearValid = false;
System.out.println("Invalid Year.");
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most like a design issue. It can have multiple solutions.

Simple is return false, after printing the first error message it would not go further.

else take stringbuffer, append all error message in one and print that. your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions brother.

wrap your checking code in a try/catch and throw an exception when something is wrong. like this:

```
          //Check to see if the date is valid
      public static boolean isValid(int day, int month, int year){

         boolean monthValid, yearValid, dayValid;
         boolean check = true;
         int dayNumber = 0;
         try{
            //check to see if the month is valid
            if(month <= 12 && month > 0){

               monthValid = true;

            }else{

               monthValid = false;
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID");
            }

            //Check to see if the year is valid
            if (year <= 3000 && year >= 1){

               yearValid = true;

            }else{

               yearValid = false;
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID");
            }

            //assigns month to a number
            if (month == JAN || month == MAR || month == MAY || month == JUL || month == AUG ||month == OCT || month == DEC){

               dayNumber = LONG;

            }else if (month == APR || month == JUN || month == SEP || month == NOV){

               dayNumber = SHORT;

            }else if (month == FEB && true == isLeapYear(year)){

               dayNumber = AKWARD;


            }else if( month == FEB){

               dayNumber = MINI;

            }

            //check to see if day is valid
            if (day < dayNumber && day > 0 || day == dayNumber){

               dayValid = true;

            }else if(day == AKWARD && false == isLeapYear(year)){

              throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID");
            }else if( day > dayNumber || day < 0){

               dayValid = false;
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID");
            }
       }catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
       {
         System.out.println("Invalid date.");
         return false;
       }
   return true; 
  }
```